# unresolved dependencies with chisel setup

Tags: chisel

I tried to set up chisel in my machine. I'm following this link:
[tutorial set up](https://chisel.eecs.berkeley.edu/latest/getting-started.html)
but when I type

make Parity.out

I get:

```
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] com.github.scct#scct_2.10;0.2!scct_2.10.jar (8159ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: edu.berkeley.cs#chisel_2.10;2.3-SNAPSHOT: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try out the latest version of the chisel-tutorial, hopefully this commit (https://github.com/ucb-bar/chisel-tutorial/commits/master) fixes your issue.

(The release version should be `latest.release`, and not `2.3-SNAPSHOT` which I believe is not publicly visible).

Comment: I thought that it's a problem of my internet connection. Because when I tried another time with different connection it works. I apologize for the silly question. Anyway, thank you.